# Некорректная работа кнопок приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Приложение что-то наподобие словаря. Есть менюшка из 4 кнопок: добавить, загрузить, удалить и выйти. После нажатия на первые три кнопки открывается диалоговое окно и дальше загружается ... словарь. Пока просто вывожу на консоль, какая кнопка была нажата и вот в чем проблема: при нажатии на добавить, выводит что были нажаты все кнопки, при нажатии на загрузить - две и лишь при нажатии на удалить, выводит что была нажата только кнопка удалить. Добавить верхняя кнопка, удалить нижняя. Не могу понять в чем дело. Вот мой обработчик событий.

```
package controllers;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
public class menuStageController {
    enum MenuItem {
        add, download, delete
    }
    private static MenuItem menuItem;
    public void bAddDictionaryPressed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        menuItem = MenuItem.add;
        this.dialogStageShow();
    }
    public void bDownloadDictionaryPressed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        menuItem = MenuItem.download;
        this.dialogStageShow();
    }
    public void bDeleteDictionaryPressed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        menuItem = MenuItem.delete;
        this.dialogStageShow();
    }
    public void exitAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void dialogStageShow() {
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        Parent loadScene = null;
        try {
            loadScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/dialogStage.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(loadScene));
        dialogStage.setResizable(false);
        dialogStage.show();
    }
    public void dialogStageAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        switch(menuItem) {
            case add:
                System.out.println("Add pressed");
            case download:
                System.out.println("Download pressed");
            case delete:
                System.out.println("Delete pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

В Вашей конструкции `switch-case`:

```
switch(menuItem) {
    case add:
        System.out.println("Add pressed");
    case download:
        System.out.println("Download pressed");
    case delete:
        System.out.println("Delete pressed");
}
```

не хватает оператора `break`. Из-за этого у Вас выполняются все блоки `case` после *подходящего под условие*.

Правильная конструкция будет выглядеть так:

```
switch(menuItem) {
    case add:
        System.out.println("Add pressed");
        break;
    case download:
        System.out.println("Download pressed");
        break;
    case delete:
        System.out.println("Delete pressed");
        break;
}
```

Здесь, после *подходящего под условие* блока будет выполнен оператор `break`, в результате чего выполнение программы будет продолжено сразу после конструкции `switch-case`, минуя все последующие `case` данной конструкции.

Comment: Можно задать еще один вопрос. Почему, если menuItem обьявить без static, выдает ошибку NullPointerException? Как так получается, что menuItem не инициализирована? Я же в любом случае вначале нажму на одну из кнопок, а потом уже открою dialogStage. Есть предположение, что дело в потоках, в которых я пока не силен.

Comment: @ДенисСавенко, Сложно сказать не видя всего кода. Лучше создайте новый вопрос, куда поместите всю имеющуюся информацию.